# C++ equality to PHP function pack/unpack

Tags: php, c++, pack, unpack

I'm searching equivalent solution to php function pack/unpack in C++.
Please look at that example:

```
<?php

    echo implode (unpack('H*',pack("V*", 554468702)));

?>
```

that will generate:

```
5e850c21
```

I need do same operation in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would achieve exactly what your PHP code does

```
 std::cout << std::hex << htonl(554468702) << std::endl;
```

However, that is ONE use-case of PHP pack/unpack, and it's an extremely generic pair of functions that can do lots of other things, which have a varying degree of complexity in C++.

Comment: thanks, to use htonl need add some extra parameters during compilation?

Comment: Yes, you will need to add an `#include` for that - which one depends on the system you are programming on.